# Como mostrar um push notification na tela de bloqueio do iOS usando flutter e o FCM

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging

Segui vários tutoriais e não estou conseguindo mostrar na tela de bloqueio no iphone a notificação usando flutter e o FCM.
Segui as etapas:

1. Habilitei meu app na minha conta da apple para notificações
2. Importei os certificados desenvolvimento e produção para o firebase
   cloud
3. Exlcui todos os provisiomentos para evitar conflitos do meu mac
4. Criei novos provisionamentos para produção e desenvolvimento
5. Configurei o xcode 11 + compatible para backgound e push
   notification
6. Inseri o código abaixo no delegate

> ```
> if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
>   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? 
>  UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
> }
> ```

7. Inseri no info.plist

   FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled como falso, tentei string NO e deu no mesmo.
8. Fiz a solicitação da permissão para notificação antes de tudo. Segui
   todo o passo-a-passo do site oficial do plugin [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)

Recebo a mensagem no método onMessage, onLaunch usando código abaixo e vejo a mensagem enviada no console do android studio ou Xcode:

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");

  },

  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");

  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");

  },
);
```

Estou usando o postman para enviar a mensagem:

```
  {"notification":{"title":"Conteúdo liberado","body":"O conteúdo foi 
  liberado Veja e confira as novidades"},"data":{"click_action": 
  "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK","nome":" ","type":"recursos","title":"Conteúdo 
  liberado","body":"Conteúdo liberado veja e confira as novidades", 
 "icon":"user.svg"},"registration_ids":["xxxxxx"]}
```

Para o android tudo funciona e mostra na tela de bloqueio, mas não estou conseguindo mostrar a notificação na tela do bloqueio do iOS, a grande maioria dos tutoriais foca apenas no Android e fala muito superficial com o iOS.

Alguém tem alguma dica? Tenho 3 semanas buscando essa solução. Acredito que seja alguma configuração nativa no Xcode que esteja faltando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após muita pesquisa, achei o problema. Na documentação oficial do plugin [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)

não informa que o "Xcode" não inclui a referência do arquivo entitlements para a compilação no modo debug e release. Foi só copiar a referência(caminho do arquivo) RunnerProfile.entitlements no local indicado em amarelo que tudo funcionou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]